# Execute function body ignoring certain lines without comments (Python)?

Tags: python, function, debugging, wing-ide

I have a couple of functions written in a single Python file. They perform a sequence of steps on a file-based dataset.
My workflow:

- After I finished coding a part of the function's body, I run the function to see how it goes.
- It may break at a certain point.
- I fix the code and re-run the function.

The problem is that when I re-run the function, it will execute the lines that were already completed successfully. Yet I want to be able to start not from the beginning but rather from an arbitrary point. This is because the whole function runs for several minutes and it would be a waste time to wait for it to complete.

I could implement "checks" to see whether this operation is required (e.g., don't create a file if it already exists), but this would imply adding a lot of new validation code (e.g., make sure that the existing file does contain the content needed); in reality, my function will be run on a dataset in known format and the whole function should be executed.

The most obvious solution is to comment out the parts that were executed successfully, but it's a hustle and I got tired of commenting and uncommenting parts as I move forwards and the function gets larger.

**Are there are any better approaches than commenting out lines for ignoring certain part of the function's body when executing?**

I am on Wing IDE if this has something to do with the debugging tricks in an IDE itself.

Comment: How do you want to run a function excluding code from it? It won't be the same function any more. And if your later lines of code do not need earlier lines, think about dividing your big function in smaller ones.

Comment: maybe [pydb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/pydb/) would help

Comment: @Alex.S, you are right, it's just a sequence of operations that however need result of the work done by previous lines. It's a good idea to split a function into smaller ones, but if the code will break in the middle of any of them, I still need to go into this smaller function and comment out successfully completed lines.

Comment: @dkol, how would it help?

Comment: Wing can move the program counter to a different line in the function via the right-click popup menu, but you'd need to do this every time you run the function.I think the suggestion of refactoring the function into smaller functions is a good one -- then you can comment out or conditionalize only the function calls. You could also write tests that call some of the functions and not others.

Comment: @JohnEhresman, thanks for the move the program counter to another line tip. This is exactly what I was looking for. Convert your comment to the answer, so I could accept it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wing can move the program counter to a different line in the function via the right-click popup menu, but you'd need to do this every time you run the function. I think a better approach is to refactor the function into smaller functions -- then you can comment out or conditionalize only the function calls. You could also write tests that call some of the functions and not others.